# Django does not redirect from one view/url to another

Tags: python, django, templates

I will start with explanation of what I want to achieve.
Basically I want to display in my view(prefs) an array items on a page that each item looks like button and if clicked it redirects to a view(results) and passes an argument(i.e itself)

My views.py look like this

```
def prefs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in user_queryset(request): #this function returns an array
            if i in request.POST.values():
                    return redirect(reverse('results',kwargs={'UserChoice':i}))
    elif not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse('Please login or sign-up to use this feature')
    else:
        uid = request.user
        return render(request,'test.html',{'form':user_queryset(request,uid)})

def results(request,UserChoice):
        if request.method =='GET':
            return render(request,'test2.html',{'objects':request_places(request,UserChoice)}) #another function that I need to use the arguments in
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'places/$',views.prefs,name='prefs'),
url(r'^places/results/(?P<UserChoice>[^\/]*)/$', views.results, name='results')
```

and my templates

test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
            <form action="" >
                        {% for obj in  form %}
     <!--<input type="text" name="{{ obj }} ">-->
            <input type="submit" value="{{ obj }}">
            </form>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
    </ul>
```

and test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <li>
        {% for items in objects %}
        <h>{{ items.name }} - {{ items.formatted_address }}</h>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your current status?  Do you receive any error?

Comment: @rajkris well after 'trial and error' in my templates at this point it does not even redirect, but before that it redirected to a 'test2.html' page, not a url :/

Comment: Could you post both the html pages? test.html and test2.html

Comment: Updated the post @rajkris

Comment: Why post then redirect when you could just put a link in your template ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I need to pass an argument that is in the POST method and the next url/view needs that argument in order to display the contents

Comment: @nexla in your example you do NOT need to post anything, you could just build the links to `results` in the `test.html` template (using the `{% url %}` templatetag).  You only need to POST/redirect when you have data to create/update/delete, this is not the case here.

Comment: I kind of understand where you are going, but could you please elaborate, because in my view i am trying to redirect and pass an argument Im rendering/using a function that uses the argument from the initial view(i.e `prefs` ) and im not sure how redirecting to url can pass an argument from `{% url 'results' %)` to a function later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. As a matter of style I recommend that you use the login decorator in your views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
```

Second. If you aim to do a POST method you should declare it in your HTML file, plus add the needed crsf token.

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
```

Third. Why would a simple link tag with an href attribute would not suffice you for any given object?

```
<a href="results/{{obj.pk}}/">{{obj}}</a>
```

In urls.py:

```
urls.py: url(r'^places/results/(?P<UserChoice>[0-9]+)/$', views.results, name='results')
```

In views.py:

```
obj='object_name'.objects.get(pk=UserChoice)
```

Then your desired object is called obj you can either passed it in a HttpResponse or in a context

I hope it helps!

Comment: it does redirect, however In case I return HttpResponse it doesn't display the object :( 
at least on a right path now :)

Comment: In urls.py: url(r'^places/results/(?P<UserChoice>[0-9]+)/$', views.results, name='results')
In views.py obj='object_name'.objects.get(pk=UserChoice). Then your desired object is called obj you can either passed it in a HttpResponse or in a context.